# What is ">?=" operator in c++?

Tags: c++, g++, shorthand

I came across this piece of code. Can anyone explain what the operator does? I tried searching SO,internet but couldn't find info on it.

```
....
int add=0;
for(int i=0; i<l; i++)
   add >?= doit(x+1, y+1, n);
....
```

I found the code in one of user solutions on TopCoder.

Comment: There is no such operator. C++ doesn't allow custom operators. This is probably a macro that's meant to appear as an operator

Comment: how do you can write a macro like that?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] with it? If it compiles, what compiler are you using?

Comment: You shouldn't but [this CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31783/Custom-User-Defined-Operators-in-C) tutorial shows how. Should be avoided for the obvious WT? factor. The tutorial uses this macro `#define contains == CCustomOperatorHelper_contains() ==` and overloaded `==` operators to grab the arguments on either side

Comment: @BiagioFesta, you can't. A macro name must be a valid identifier token.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, in the link you added `contains` is the macro name, which *is* a valid identifier token. `>?=` is not.

Comment: @StoryTeller yes. And the duplicate shows that this isn't about C++ after all. Just an ancient compiler extension

Comment: @mtk next time mention the compiler you use. Where *did* you find this code? I think `std::min` and `std::max` were already available 20 years ago

Comment: *"Finally, your operators have to be a-zA-Z0-9_ based, just like everything else. The reason has to do with limitations in the macro symbols that make it impossible to declare operators like >>> or anything else with a symbol. You can still use really short symbols, though I would capitalize them and avoid using single letters."* your link

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: If you follow the link, you will see that they were *actually* a g++ extension that only applied to c++.

Comment: Ah.  Maybe that is what you were saying.  Sorry.

Comment: I found the code in one of user solutions on TopCoder